# Перенаправление через JS

Tags: javascript

Есть следующий [сайт](http://iphonestore.kz/). Мне необходимо сделать перенаправление на страницу благодарности после отправки формы. Не знаю как. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
function Formdata(data){
     /* если не заполнено поле Ваше имя, длина менее 3-x*/

    if(data.name != null && data.name.value.length == 0){
        alert('поле "Имя" пустое');
        return false;
    }

    if(data.name.value == data.name.title){
        alert('поле "Имя" пустое');
        return false;
    }

    if(data.phone != null && data.phone.value.length == 0){
        alert('поле "Контактный телефон" пустое');
        return false;
    }

    if(data.phone.value == data.phone.title){
        alert('поле "Контактный телефон" пустое');
        return false;
    }

    if(data.phone != null && data.phone.value.length < 5){
        alert('поле "Контактный телефон" должно содержать минимум пять символов');
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Спасибо! Мы обязательно свяжемся с вами');
        $(".popup").fadeOut(500);
        return window.location.href = "http://iphonestore.kz/thank.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Наверное, надо просто:

    window.location.= 'http://iphonestore.kz/thank.html

Или что конкретно у вас не получается?

Comment: И так, и так пробовал, просто ничего не происходит после появления попапа с надписью с благодарностями.

Comment: Ваша форма, это всплывающее окно с классом .popup? До алерта со "Спасибо..." доходит?

Comment: Может, нужно убрать return? Если не поможет, покажите, что пишется в консоли.

Comment: @ModaL, я же уже предлагал вариант без return.

Comment: До алерта со спасибо доходит, консоль чиста, ошибок нет, но при этом после того, как нажимаешь "ок" на алерте со спасибо, ничего не происходит.

Comment: @Bkvalexe, вы return убрали? А окно .popup исчезает?

Comment: Значит нужно убрать alert.